# How pipe to zsh read?

Tags: shell, pipe, zsh

With **bash** everything is fine:

```
$ yes | bash -c 'read -sn 1 -p "[Y/n] " RESPONSE ; echo $RESPONSE'
y
```

But with **zsh** I have trouble:

```
$ yes | zsh -c 'read -sk 1 "RESPONSE?[Y/n] " ; echo $RESPONSE'
[Y/n]
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with the question; but if you used single quotes for the outer layer you could eliminate all of the ugly backslashes (in both versions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `-k` option is used, zsh's `read` command will read from the terminal unless instructed otherwise. This is documented in the appropriate section of the `zshbuiltins` manpage. Your pipe is supplying the standard input for the script, but that has no effect on attempts to read from the terminal.

You can add `-u 0` to the call to `read` to tell it to read from standard input (file descriptor 0) even when other options (such as `-k`) would cause it to read from elsewhere.

Comment: So is there just a single way to do this?
`yes | zsh -c 'if [[ -t 0 ]] ; then read -sk 1 "RESPONSE?[Y/n] " ; else read -u 0 -sk 1 "RESPONSE?[Y/n] " ; fi ; echo $RESPONSE'`

Comment: You should be able to just use `-u 0` in either case. If I'm reading that code correctly (hard to read code in comments) it's checking if file descriptor 0 is a terminal, if it goes with the default for `read` to read from the terminal, otherwise it specifies to read from file descriptor 0. If the test passes it shouldn't hurt to specify the file descriptor; it will be reading from the terminal in either case.

Comment: It should read from terminal by default, but understand input from stdin when piped.